# If OptionButton is active TextBox is mandatory

Tags: excel, vba

In my UserForm I have several frames, several OptionButtons and several TextBoxes. one example you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

Now I want that if I check the medium or high risk OptionButton the TextBox ("- Comment Risk -") should be mandatory and if it is empty or nothin was added an error message should be shown.

This is my macro so far:

```
Sub Comment_Check()
    'obMedium = OptionButton "Medium"
    'obHigh = OptionButton "High"
    'txtRisk = TextBox "- Comment Risk -"

    With UserForm1
        For x = 1 to 6
            If .Controls("obMedium" & x).Value = True Or .Controls("obHigh" & x).Value = True _
            And .Controls("txtRisk" & x).Value = "" Or .Controls("txtRisk" & x).Value = "- Comment Risk -" Then
                .Controls("txtRisk" & x).BackColor = RGB(255, 75, 80)
                MsgBox "Error Message"
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Now my problem is, if I check `Medium` and write something in the risk TextBox, the TextBox will be colored red and the error message is shown. If I check `High` and write something to the TextBox everything works fine.

What do I have to change that both ways will work.

Comment: Use parenthesis to organize your if statement - something like `If (cond1 or cond2) and (cond3 or cond4)`

Comment: @braX that is to easy :) thanks a lot, it works fine.

Comment: Just a note, I recommend to write `- Comment Risk -` and `- Comment Chance -` into a Label control above the TextBoxes instead of writing it into the TextBox itself (which is not a good practice). Because if the user has written somenthing into both boxes he will not know anymore which is the risk and which is the chance box. Also your code will be easier.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for your recommendation. i will add some labels for that.

Comment: diem, if any of the "probability"'s checkbox is selected, then will "comment risk" be mandatory?

Comment: @SiddharthRout no "probability" checkboxes do not effect the textboxes. these optionbuttons are only for information. only if Medium or High are selected, then the TB will be mandatory

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you have to use parenthesis to group your `Or` & `And` satements logically.

Furthermore I suggest the following changes:

1. Write `- Comment Risk -` and `- Comment Chance -` into a Label control above the TextBoxes instead of writing it into the TextBox itself. So the user always can see which is which even when filled with data. Also the code would be easier.
2. Use a switch `ErrorOccured` that you turn `True` in your loop, otherwise you will get 6 error messages in a row (worst case).
3. Use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables properly.

Something like the following should work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Comment_Check()
    Dim ErrorOccured As Boolean

    With UserForm1
        Dim x As Long
        For x = 1 to 6
            If (.Controls("obMedium" & x).Value Or .Controls("obHigh" & x).Value) _
               And .Controls("txtRisk" & x).Value = vbNullString Then
                .Controls("txtRisk" & x).BackColor = RGB(255, 75, 80)
                ErrorOccured = True
            End If
        Next x
    End With

    If ErrorOccured Then
        MsgBox "Error Message"
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to turn them non-red in a second run (eg. if you re-check after the user corrected his edit) then add a

```
ElseIf (.Controls("obMedium" & x).Value Or .Controls("obHigh" & x).Value) And .Controls("txtRisk" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
    .Controls("txtRisk" & x).BackColor = RGB(50, 168, 82) 'green
    'don't set ErrorOccured to False here!
```

right before the `End If` line otherwise the box will stay red even if the user corrected his edit.